# ArcObjects: How to make non-feature-linked annotation features with a simple line callout that remains functional?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, annotation

I would like to make simple line callout annotation that is not feature-linked but remains functional when it is manually moved, i.e. the anchor point remains on the feature while the text moves.  I have tried making graphic text elements with simple line callouts and loading them into an annotation feature; however, the text box and leader line are combined into a static graphic when loaded into annotation.  The leader line is no longer functional; the anchor point doesn't stay anchored.  How might I do this programmatically in ArcObjects?  Will this only work if I automatically generate annotation from the feature class I wish to annotate?

Any answers or insights would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks, all.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "stays anchored" in your description?  Do you mean that moves entirely with the text of that the anchor point remains on the feature when the text moves?

Comment: I meant that the anchor point remains on the feature.  I have edited my question accordingly.  Thanks, Craig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need feature linked annotation to get this behavior.  From an ArcObjects standpoint, once the AnchorPoint is set on the callout, it will remain when the annotation is edited.  Post code if you are doing this and it is not working.

Comment: Thank you, Craig.  It is good to know that I am not going in a dead end direction with this.  Now, the trick for me is to figure out how actually to do it.  I will post a separate question with some code when I figure out something specific to ask.

Comment: I have posted an expanded version of this question with code samples [here ...](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8535/how-do-i-programmatically-create-non-feature-linked-simple-line-callout-annotati)