# How do I control the ZOrder of annotation classes in a geodatabase annotation feature class?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, annotation

Let's say I have an annotation feature class with three annotation classes--anno1, anno2, and anno3--and I want to have anno1 on top, anno2 in the middle, and anno3 on the bottom.  Can I and where do I set this zorder?  Also, assuming zorder index starts at 0, is 0 on the bottom or the top?

I thought that the order in which I defined the annotation classes when I created the annotation feature class determined the zorder, but apparently that isn't true.  I didn't see any specific interface in the interactive process to set the zorder of the annotation classes.  Can I (do I have to) do it after the fact with ArcObjects?  That would be fine.  If so, what are the recommended interfaces to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drawing is not done by subclass, so you can't control the order.  The order is determined by the feature return order from the database, which according to database theory should not be relied on to be determinable.

Comment: Well, that's just peachy.  Guess I should have asked this earlier.  It sinks my ship.  Thanks you, Craig

Comment: Hmmm, another idea ... What if I have an IFDOGraphicsLayer2 on my annotation layer and call DoAddFeature like thus:  'pFDOGraphicsLayer2.DoAddFeature(pFeature, pElement, zorder)`. Then I could specify a zorder ... but I'm not sure what that zorder is and how it affects annotation drawing.  Any thoughts on this?

Comment: While the API has a ZOrder, it is not used for draw order.  How exactly are you trying to control order and why?  Understanding this may help me recommend a better solution.

Comment: It's related to the [other question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8535/how-do-i-programmatically-create-non-feature-linked-simple-line-callout-annotati) you have been helping me with.  I create anno features that have graphic GroupElements as their elements, so these features do not support callouts.  My idea was to create another piece of transparent, dummy annotation underneath each of the others that will carry a callout leader line.  Kludgy but functional.  I haven't gotten the SharedSymbol thing to work yet, though -- Python syntax problem.